# Как написать Windows приложение на C++ под веб сервис?

Tags: c++

Пример: есть веб сервис, при загрузке определённой страницы в веб-браузере мы сохраняем весь HTML код в какой либо файл. Возможно ли, реализовать данную задачу средствами языка программирования C++?

Comment: не понятно, в чем задача? сохранять HTML, загруженный браузером, на локальной машине? сохранять сгенерированный HTML на сервере? сохранять чужой HTML на сервере?

Comment: краткий ответ - да. используя язык си++ можно сделать практически все.

Comment: Более полный - используя, конечно же, сторонние библиотеки или API операционной системы. Потому что в *чистом* C++ нет никакого понятия о веб-сервисах, HTML и иже с ним...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, но вам придется использовать сетевые возможности операционной системы - сокеты, чтобы соединиться по сети. Реализовать протокол HTTP можно как самостоятельно, так и воспользовавшись готовой библиотекой (не стандартной библиотекой C++, в ней такого нет).

Под Windows почитать о Windows Sockets можно [тут](http://www.firststeps.ru/mfc/net/socket/r.php?1).